# Scala - tapir dynamic status codes type mismatching

Tags: scala, tapir

I am creating an endpoint in tapir that requires dynamic status codes for the error out.

I have declared a seal trait `FailureResponse` and i have created case classes that extends this trait. Similar to the example shown https://tapir-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoint/statuscodes.html

**Model**

```
object AuthenticationModel {

  case class Request(productId: String)

  case class SuccessResponse(success: Boolean, status: Int, data: Token, message: String)

  sealed trait FailureResponse
  case class FailureResponse400(success: Boolean, status: Int = 400, errors: Array[Error], message: String) extends FailureResponse
  case class FailureResponse401(success: Boolean, status: Int = 401, errors: Array[Error], message: String) extends FailureResponse
  case class FailureResponse422(success: Boolean, status: Int = 422, errors: Array[Error], message: String) extends FailureResponse
  case class FailureResponse500(success: Boolean, status: Int = 500, errors: Array[Error], message: String) extends FailureResponse

  case class Token(token: String)
  case class Error(code: String, message: String)

}
```

**Endpoint**

```
object Auth {

  val authenticationEndpoint : Endpoint[AuthenticationModel.Request, AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse, AuthenticationModel.SuccessResponse, Unit] = endpoint
    .tag("Auth")
    .description("Generates an idcheck token using product id")
    .post
    .in("auth")
    .in(jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.Request])
    .out(jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.SuccessResponse])
    .errorOut(oneOf(
      statusMapping(StatusCode.BadRequest, jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse400]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.Unauthorized, jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse401]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.UnprocessableEntity, jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse422]),
      statusMapping(StatusCode.InternalServerError, jsonBody[AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse500]),
    ))

}
```

I have set the error-output parameter type to be `AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse`.

However i am getting a type mis match

> Required AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse
>   Found AuthenticationModel.FailureResponse with Product with Serializable

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the error message:

just change your

`sealed trait FailureResponse`

to

`sealed trait FailureResponse extends Product with Serializable`

I hope you already have managed to resolve this problem/